# android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I wrote a little code, but I had a problem. Error that I encounter as: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
  I looked at the questions that look like this, but the answers that were given did not solve my problem. Can you help me?
Java code as:

```
public class Fehrest extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseManager dbManager = new DatabaseManager();
    int tedad,tedad_fav;
    private String[] Name, Text,Image,seen, English, Farsi;
    private int[] id,fav,id_sen;
    Items items = new Items();
    SharedPreferences sharedP;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Story_Adapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Book_Items> MyArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    String button_name,tbl_name="story_tbl";
    TextView txt_toolbar,txt_sen;
    BrokenView brokenView;
    BrokenTouchListener listener;
    EditText edt_search;
    LinearLayout lin_main;
    RelativeLayout rlt_buttons;
    boolean night_mode,show_english=true;
    int day=0,date_mod,today;
    Button btn_love,btn_pand,btn_tanz,btn_mazhabi;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.movies_list);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rcl_movies);
        edt_search = findViewById(R.id.edt_search);
        rlt_buttons = findViewById(R.id.rlt_buttons);
        txt_toolbar = findViewById(R.id.txt_toolbar);
        lin_main = findViewById(R.id.lin_main);
        txt_sen = findViewById(R.id.txt_sen);
        btn_love = findViewById(R.id.btn_love);
        btn_pand = findViewById(R.id.btn_pand);
        btn_mazhabi = findViewById(R.id.btn_mazhabi);
        btn_tanz = findViewById(R.id.btn_tanz);

        brokenView = BrokenView.add2Window(Fehrest.this);
        listener = new BrokenTouchListener.Builder(brokenView).build();

        sharedP = getSharedPreferences(Items.SETTINGS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        night_mode = sharedP.getBoolean(Items.NIGHT_MODE,false);
        today = sharedP.getInt(Items.TODAY,0);
        date_mod = sharedP.getInt(Items.DATE_MODIFIED,0);
        day = (today - date_mod);
        get_night();
        Get_sentence();
        adapter = new Story_Adapter(this, MyArrayList);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Fehrest.this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        button_name = getIntent().getStringExtra("button");
```

and this my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fehrest"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/lin_main"
    android:background="@drawable/background4">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lin_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@color/nephritis"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:weightSum="7"
        >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_search"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:background="@drawable/textviewstyle2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="جستجو..."
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/White"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:text="لیست خانوائخ خاا"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="21sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/medium"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_search"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/magnify"
            android:onClick="img_search_click"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rcl_movies"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rlt_buttons">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_sen"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/textviewstyle"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/zahraroosta"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="Sentence"
                    android:textColor="@color/description"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_love"
                    android:layout_width="290dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/txt_sen"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/back_btn3"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/boldmayriad"
                    android:onClick="btn_click"
                    android:paddingEnd="40dp"
                    android:text="@string/euphorbiaceae"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/White"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />
```

This is part of my MLX code and the tags are not closed for this reason.

Comment: the id you are getting is of relative layout, and you are setting it to recycle view, that is why it is giving that error

Comment: by checking your layout, the id your are getting for recycle view is okay. Try invaliding the cache and then run.

Comment: and can you add the specific line on which it is throwing error ?

Comment: No, unfortunately I can't add a line that throwing the error

Comment: I did what you said, but it didn't work, and it gave me the same error again